# Jsoup select links for different websites

Tags: java, jsoup

I am filtering links out of a html body using JSOUP.

for such a webpage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing

i want to filter links such as:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light

for hash tag links en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#cite_note-1

i try `doc.select("a[href*=#]").remove();` and it works well where hash tag links  in page html src: `<a href="#cite_ref-1">`

but when i use      `doc.select("a[href]*=/]").remove();`    where links in page html src

```
<a href="/wiki/Light">CH</a>
```

But there are still links not filtered . How is this possible?

Comment: If my answer solved the problem you described, then you should accept it so the thread can be considered closed. If not, then please provide some feedback so I can update my answer

Comment: Thanks alot i checked ur answer again with my code and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
doc.select("a[href]*=/]").remove();
```

It should be like this

```
doc.select("a[href*=/]").remove();
```

But this would remove every link containing a `/`.
Is this what you want, or do you want to remove every link that starts with `/`.
In that case you need this

```
doc.select("a[href^=/]").remove();
```

Comment: @ alkis i tried doc.select("a[href^=/]").remove(); to remove every link that starts with / but i got the those exception org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml. Mimetype=application/pdf, URL=http://france.emc.com/collateral/white-paper/h12825-cloud-foundry-paas-vblock-wp.pdf

Comment: This is a completely different url from the one you posted in your question. Moreover this problem is completely different from the one you mention in your question. Please update your question.